# VB.NET Serial Data Parsing

Tags: vb.net

I’m trying to read a stream of data from serial port coming from a digital scale. 
If I send the data stream on a textbox I have a correct visualization (except first line) 
[Stream in textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUz2q.jpg)

I would like to catch only one row to use this data. 
I have try with following code

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim alol As String
    alol = SerialPort1.ReadLine
    Label1.Text = alol
End Sub
```

but what append is that every time I click the button, the label, instead of showing the row value "+0000.26kg", take different section of the data stream (EG: "+00" "KG" "000.2" "+0000.26k" ".26kg" and so on.)

Can anyone suggest to me a way to catch this value ?
The string of interest start always with + or - symbol and end with, I guess, a return.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would check is the parameters on your SerialPort1 control. Make sure the baud rate in particular is set to a value that is supported by your actual serial port.